# Shifting all columns through a loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to shift my Dataframe through a loop. I have the following dataframe;

```
           A          B     
0         0.0         101   
1         0.0  101.996163   
2         0.0  209.987279   
3         0.0  168.605494   
4         0.0  138.245242
```

I can shift each column by using the following code;

```
for col in df.columns:
    df["%s_%s"%(col,-1)] = df[col].shift(1)
```

The output I would get  from the above code is;

```
           A          B            A_-1    B_-1
0         0.0  101.996163          NaN     NaN
1         0.0  209.987279          0       101.996163
2         0.0  168.605494          0       209.987279
3         0.0  138.245242          0       168.605494
```

But what if I have to create additional columns, each representing different time lags e.g. would like to shift each column by 10? Is there a way of doing this (maybe by using a loop)?

Comment: `df.shift(10)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another `for`:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for i in range(1,5):
        df["%s_%s_%s"%(col,i,-1)] = df[col].shift(i)

print (df)
     A           B  A_1_-1  A_2_-1  A_3_-1  A_4_-1      B_1_-1      B_2_-1  \
0  0.0  101.000000     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN   
1  0.0  101.996163     0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN  101.000000         NaN   
2  0.0  209.987279     0.0     0.0     NaN     NaN  101.996163  101.000000   
3  0.0  168.605494     0.0     0.0     0.0     NaN  209.987279  101.996163   
4  0.0  138.245242     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  168.605494  209.987279   

       B_3_-1  B_4_-1  
0         NaN     NaN  
1         NaN     NaN  
2         NaN     NaN  
3  101.000000     NaN  
4  101.996163   101.0
```

If need shift all columns by some N like `3` :

```
for col in df.columns:
    df["%s_%s"%(col,-1)] = df[col].shift(3)

print (df)
     A           B  A_-1        B_-1
0  0.0  101.000000   NaN         NaN
1  0.0  101.996163   NaN         NaN
2  0.0  209.987279   NaN         NaN
3  0.0  168.605494   0.0  101.000000
4  0.0  138.245242   0.0  101.996163
```